# VS 2019: Create an environment variable to use in test projects

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2019

Is there an option to set, in Visual Studio 2019, environment variables that can be read by test code, when running using the built-in test explorer?
In my test project's properties, I've tried defining the env variable under the 'debug' tab, but I wasn't able to read it in my test code.